# Best way to save date and time in csv file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, datetime

Which way is most optimal to save datetime in csv in python?
I have an app which takes measurements once a second and save it to csv files.
I use 2 columns: time and date, but python has datetime object and is it better to merge these columns into once ~ datetime?
The files should be also 'excel format friendly'.

Comment: I would personally use a Unix timestamp, particularly if the data did not need to be human friendly, but that in an opinion on my part and this site is not keen on opinions and questions that seek them out.

Comment: Besides being opinionated, I don't think there's a general answer, it depends on the application. Unix time might be fine for some, [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for others, but maybe you also need a time zone (DST ...)? Excel likes to be a pain in my experience, and maybe you also want this to be human-friendly?!

Comment: *DON'T* use Unix timestamps. No humans understand them, very few applications can use them without conversion and even then, you have no way of knowing what timezone they refer to. Even if people argue they're always UTC, how do you convert them to a meaningful local time, when the original timezone information is lost? The standard is ISO 8601, ie `YYYY-MM-DD`. There's no way to specify a date with Unix timestamps either

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos isn't it a bit too easy to disregard unix time in general? I mean, if you don't add at least a UTC offset to your ISO 8601 string, you don't know anything about the timezone either.

Comment: @FObersteiner no. Not when you're the one that has to parse the unfortunate strings provided by various external companies. There's a very good reason people settled on ISO8601. Never mind YYYY-MM-DD takes less space than a 64-bit integer serialized as text.